# Users with default picture and grayed out name

Tags: support, user-information

There are some users who have a certain preset icon, and you can't access their profiles. For example the user that asked this question:   [Using a transistor with AC?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/using-a-transistor-with-ac).

Why does this happen? Are they deleted?

Comment: Thanks,I wasn't sure how to say it

Comment: You got it right, those are deleted users.

Comment: Then it'll just get closed

Comment: Vote up??Thanks..but what for?